# Deleting document from Firestore based on array key

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a web app to help people create graphs. When a user creates two graphs and deletes the first one, the index in the array changes to 0 and so the second graph (graph1) doesn't get deleted from Firestore. Any ideas on how to approach this? Thanks

**Adds Graph**

```
onClick={ () => {
    
        const clientDb = firebaseClient.firestore();  
            
            // Adding Graph Options NOTICE HERE SITTING DOCUMENT NAME TO graph${i}
             for(var i = 0 ; i < numberofGraphs.length ; i++ ){
        
              clientDb.collection("Users").doc(props.uid).collection("Dashboard").doc(`graph${i}`).set({ 
                  type:numberofGraphs[i].type,
                  title:numberofGraphs[i].type,
                   seriestitle:numberofGraphs[i].seriestitle,
                  legend:numberofGraphs[i].legend,
                   xAxis:numberofGraphs[i].xAxis,
              yAxis:numberofGraphs[i].yAxis,
              color:numberofGraphs[i].color,
              tooltipcolor:numberofGraphs[i].tooltipcolor,
              tooltiptextcolor:numberofGraphs[i].tooltiptextcolor,
              axisColor:numberofGraphs[i].axisColor,
            })  
        
          }
    
    }}
```

**Deletes Graph**

```
numberofGraphs.map( (si, k) => (
   <>
   <CloseIcon  

   onClick={ () => {

    if(window !== "undefined") {

      console.log("lets see it")

      const clientDb = firebaseClient.firestore();  

              //NOTICE HERE DELETING Graph with index from map 
    clientDb.collection("Users").doc(props.uid).collection("Dashboard").doc(`graph${k}`).delete();
    
              }

          
         const newgraphs = numberofGraphs.filter( (object, kk) =>  k!== kk ) 
         setnumberofGraphs(newgraphs);
       
       }}

         />  
<CreateGraph2 type={si.type} title={si.title} seriestitle={si.seriestitle}/>
         
           </>

     ))
```

Comment: Just a heads up that you have `title: numberofGraphs[i].type` hidden in there, probably should be copying across the title prop.

Comment: I recommend having a read of [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), while it talks about the RTDB, its concerns also apply to Firestore and any online database. The better approach is to use automatic document IDs for the documents and then order them on the client by creation time rather than store them in the database by numeric index. I'd also recommend moving all graphs to their own `/Graphs` collection or subcollection rather than have them in `/Dashboard`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue doing the following:

**Adds Graph**

```
//   Took @samthecodingman's advice by moving all graphs to their own /Graphs collection. 
//   Which also resonated with @Brian's answer to use 
//   collection().add() to add documents with Auto-generated ID's instead of adding graphs based
//     on index no. of array.

    onClick={ () => {

          if(window !== "undefined") {

    const clientDb = firebaseClient.firestore();  
  
      clientDb.collection("Users").doc(props.uid)
      .collection("Dashboard")
      .doc("First").collection("Graphs").add({ 
        type:type, title:title, seriestitle:seriestitle,
        legend:legend,
         xAxis:xAxis, 
        yAxis:yAxis,  
        color:color,
        tooltipcolor:tooltipcolor,
        tooltiptextcolor:tooltiptextcolor,
        axisColor:axisColor,
//passed an id filed to the object I'm saving
        id:type+title
    })  

  
      }
        
        }}
```

**Deletes Graph**

```
//mapping through an array of objects (si) and then using the get() method with 

a query to check for matching ID. Then used the id in the delete method

  if(window !== "undefined") {

    const clientDb = firebaseClient.firestore();  

   const docref = clientDb.collection("Users").doc(props.uid)
     .collection("Dashboard").doc("First").collection("Graphs"); 
     docref.where("id" , "==", `${si.type}${si.title}`)
     .get()
     .then((querySnapshot) => {
         querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              docref.doc(doc.id).delete()
             console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data() );
         });
     })
 
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to do it this way you could "mark doc as deleted" by doing `collection('Dashboard').doc('<doc-to-delete>').set({ deleted: true })` and then just filter it out in the client by this property and don't display it.

More generally - use `collection().add()` to create new documents and let firestore auto-generate IDs for you. Then access your documents by ID, instead of trying to keep track of indices on the front end.

Comment: So basically whenever user creates a graph I should directly add his input into a collection on firestore and then read and map to frontend directly from the database ?

Comment: No, I didn't say anything about mapping database values to the frontend, directly or otherwise. In short my answer was - don't try to assign IDs to the documents yourself based on their position in an array on the frontend. Let Firestore auto-generate IDs for you and use these IDs to work with documents.